# How to append to a TSV file using the output of a Python script

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, csv

I have some code saved in a .py file, which, for a given URL, will return the Google page ranking of the URL.

```
So on command line I will run : 

python GetRanking.py www.google.com
```

and output :

```
Traffic stats for: www.google.com
AlexaTrafficRank:1
GooglePageRank:9
```

Now, I have a .tsv file of URLs.

I would like to create a new .py file, which, for each URL, will calculate the page ranking and alexa traffic rank using GetRanking.py, and append it to the row in the .tsv file.

Currently my .tsv looks like :

```
url   PageRank   AlexaRank
www.google.com
www.foo.com
http://www.test.com
http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

The end result I want is (using dummy values, the values I want are the ones produced by the GetRanking.py file above :

```
url   PageRank   AlexaRank
www.google.com   9   1
www.foo.com   177   43432
http://www.test.com   2132   4567
http://www.stackoverflow.com   8   9
```

Comment: What error is your code giving you that you have a question about?  Or is there a particular blocker troubling you?

Comment: @DSM All of my code works to retrieve the rankings; I am simply unable to actually append to my TSV file! I cant find any simple way to do it!

Comment: You can't append horizontally to a TSV file in place, but you can easily write a new file (on top of the original, if you like).  Check out the `csv` module.

Comment: @DSM Do you know how I can save the output of another .py file in a .csv file? This is my big blocker :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to save an output of a .py file to a csv file.
You can always use csv lib.

I suppose your output can be store into a 2 dimensional list:

```
import csv
ls = [['www.google.com','9','1'],['www.foo.com','177','43432'],['http://www.test.com','2132','4567'],['http://www.stackoverflow.com','8','9']]
file = open('test.csv', 'w');
writer = csv.writer(file)
for item in ls:
    writer.writerow(item)
file.close()
```

Comment: To append as the OP specified, open with 'a' not 'w'